# Port fowarding with vlc-vlm

Tags: stream, streaming, vlc, portforwarding

I`m trying to make a music streaming server using VLC and the VLM manager. The problem which i face is the following: i have a client which is only able to read from a port and ip (e.g. http://192.168.0.1:8080)

the setup which vlm provides for a stream is in the form of ip, port and filename (e.g. http://192.168.0.1:8080/track.mp3 )

Is it possible to redirect the stream to another port? (without the filename) so that my client could connect to it?

putting the stream on the port, blocks interaction with vlm with the stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the stream in VLM with eg.

`new channel1 broadcast enabled

setup channel1 input 'file:///D:/music/artist/album/track.mp3'

setup channel1 output #standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.1.100:8586}

control channel1 play`

You will be able to read the stream with your player by connecting to http://192.168.1.100:8586
You can of course change the IP and port to your own values.
Hope that helps